# Json-made array in PHP is empty

Tags: php, python, arrays, json

I have a working Python function and I am calling it within PHP.
The Python program then puts the final data structure into a json object.

```
json.dump(data)
```

This is all working.  When I go to view the data in PHP it doesnt give me anything.

```
$myArray = json_decode(exec(python_program), true)
```

When I `print_r` the array, it is empty, nothing shows on screen.  Given that the Python works correctly it is either a json or PHP problem.

If anyone knows what I am doing wrong, I'd appreciate it being explained!

Comment: First check that you are able to successfully recover the json from the python script.

Comment: Check this works: `$json = exec(python_program); var_dump($json); exit();`

Comment: @diggersworld I'm getting string(0) "" printed on the page.  does this mean the data isnt being sent from python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#116222

> Can’t get the output from your exec’d command to appear in the $output
>   array? Is it echo’ing all over your shell instead?
>
> Append "2>&1" to the end of your command, for example:
>
> `exec("xmllint --noout ~/desktop/test.xml 2>&1", $retArr, $retVal);`
>
> Will fill the array $retArr with the expected output; one line per
>   array key.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php for how to use the exec function correctly..

> ### Return Values
>
> **The last line from the result of the command.** If you need to execute a
> command and have all the data from the command passed directly back
> without any interference, use the passthru() function.
>
> To get the output of the executed command, be sure to set and use the
> output parameter.

You are after something like...

```
$lines = array();

// the actual method
exec(python_program, $lines)
$myArray = json_decode(implode("\n", $lines), true)
```

Comment: that doesnt work the page crashes.....that actual line I have is $procList = json_decode(exec("python ./scripts/pyFile.py $procURL"), true);

Comment: @Michael: `$lines` and `$return_code` are not required. The documentation you've linked to clearly shows they're optional.

Comment: Yeah I just made an update as it was wrong, My guess is that at the end of the python output is an empty new line. The `exec` function only returns the last line.

Comment: @diggersworld Yeah mate I just removed them to fix it up

Comment: still not working.....I put the array into var_dump and got NULL printed to the screen

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($lines)`?

Comment: I also just saw this on the man page.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#116222 Append "2>&1" to the end of your command, for example:

`exec("xmllint --noout ~/desktop/test.xml 2>&1", $retArr, $retVal);`

Comment: var_dump($lines) == array(0) { }
however....appending  2>&1 to the end showed a Python traceback error....Its sorted and working again! thank you both very much!

Comment: So was the 2>&1 thing the answer? if so I will create another answer and put that in there

Comment: it showed a python error and I managed to fix it then.....it was tracing back to another file in the workflow